# Automatic upgrade php code

Tags: php, mysql, upgrade

I have found this tool that downgrade the php code from php5.4 to 5.3
https://github.com/endel/php-code-downgrade

actually do you know if there's something to upgrade from 5.3 to 5.4?
because my php code seems not to work anymore and it was in php5.3 that is no more support by my webhost

*edit: I solved at the end.. I just found out that the problem was a server configuration of the web-hosting :) (#FCGI mode)*

Comment: "Does not work" is not a diagnostic we can help you with. Maybe your computer's unplugged. Can you speak to more specific errors or behaviours?

Comment: @tadman I use a basic authentication login system, and even if it connects to the db, it doesn't accept my id/password. it worked on the webhost with php5.3, but with 5.5 it doesn't work, as I said

Comment: "Doesn't work" is still meaningless. Do you get errors? Do you get **anything**?

Comment: "even if it connects to the db, it doesn't accept my id/password" I don't have any error, but the datas does not work, that's it. I don't have any further information

Comment: Obviously you get an error or you wouldn't know it didn't accept your password, so amend your question to include that text. You've posted zero code about how you're connecting here, so it's anyone's guess as to what you're doing wrong. Post the relevant code or nobody can help you.

Comment: include a script to the top of your index.php that is able to send all  errors to your email, after adding the script you should receive all errors in your email, read http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.deprecated.php as this is where to start solving the problems with your code. if you're not able to write a script to handle errors I can provide my script and information on how to use it. please post php code that isn't working to complete your question and make it possible to answer your question.  `do you know if there's something to..` is not a good question if you do not provide code

Comment: @jagb I solved at the end.. I just found out that the problem was a server configuration of the web-hosting :) (#FCGI mode)

Comment: @Nic: I'm glad the problem has been discovered and solved and I hope everything is working just fine, if you're still using the old php 5.3 code, I would recomend to upgrade your code ASAP as php 5.3 is [dead](http://php.net/releases/5_3_29.php) and not safe to use, Good luck and happy coding

Comment: @jagb php5.4 for the moment... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP 5.4 is backward compatible with 5.3. If anything you should just be seeing notices in your error logs. Turn on error reporting E_ALL and check your logs for any issues. For a list of features deprecated between 5.3 and 5.4 check [PHP 5.4 Deprecated Features.](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.deprecated.php)

Comment: actually some functions are deprecated and my site (written in php5.3) does not work on a php5.5 webhost @aronkerr